# KeyPressed event not firing on list view cell in JavaFX8

Tags: java, listview, javafx-8, keypress

I have a list view with the following cell factory:

```
availableSymbolsTable.setCellFactory(lv -> {
            ListCell<Symbol> cell = new ListCell<Symbol>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Symbol t, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(t, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        setText(t.getSymbolName());
                    }
                }
            };

           cell.setOnKeyPressed(e -> 
              {
                  //This never fires
              }
          );

            cell.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
             //This works
            });

            cell.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                if (cell.getItem() != null) {
                    if(e.getClickCount() == 2)
                    {
                    //This works
                    }
                }
            });
            return cell ;
        } );
```

I have added 3 event handles in the same manner. OnMouseEntered and OnMouseClicked both work as expected. However, OnKeyPressed is never executed. The same goes for OnKeyReleased. When pressing arrow keys, the listview changes the selected row as expected, but my event handler code is never executed. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: keyevents are routed to the focusOwner - a cell rarely is.

Comment: @kleopatra So you are saying I should set the onKeyPressed on the whole tableView, not on each cell? No way to do it on cells?

Comment: depends ... what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @kleopatra Basically get the cells encapsulated item and call a method on it. I ommited it from the question but this is what I do in mouseClicked: cell.getItem().MyMethod(). I want to do the same thing on Enter press

Comment: then it's yes, I think

Comment: @kleopatra Just for knowledge sake... in which case it's a no then?